# Eclipse misses a warning (enum in switch)

Tags: java, eclipse, enums

I am using Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 (J2EE edition) and Java 6 on OS X 10.9.2.

Suppose I have an enum:

```
public enum Colors { RED, GREEN, BLUE }
```

Suppose I have a switch using it:

```
Colors color = ...
switch (color) {
  case RED: return something();
  case BLUE: return somethingElse();
  default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown color: " color);
}
```

It's clear I have forgotten to add a label for `GREEN` (perhaps I added it later). Eclipse correctly tells me this is the case: `color` in the `switch()` statement is underlined like this:

[image: Underlined word color]

[image: Warning text]

And the warning message says:

```
The enum constant GREEN should have a corresponding case label in this enum switch on Colors. 
To suppress this problem, add a comment //$CASES-OMITTED$ on the line above the 'default:'
```

**My problem:** this warning does not show up, neither in the Markers view, nor in the Problems view! Right now the only way to find it is go to the code with the `switch()` and see the yellow underline.

This should probably not be the case that my Markers are filtering this out: Configure Contents > Show all items is checked, and yet the warning is not in the list.

What am I doing wrong?

*Update:* Changing the warning level of this to Error does not help - my code shows a red underline, but still no error in the Problems/Markers. 
Fresh Eclipse download, fresh workspace fixes the problem.
Switching between different perspectives (J2EE/Java) does not help.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting this warning _at all_? The `default` will handle `GREEN`, so there should be no warning. Can not reproduce. I get the warning either in all the places, or (with default) not at all.

Comment: Eclipse is underlining the word `color`, therefore there _is_ a warning. I just need to see it in a list of warnings.

Comment: Maybe that's the spell checker or another plugin? Hover over it with your mouse to see the details. As long as you've got your default case, you should be fine.

Comment: Look at the screenshots. The thing is: I **want** this warning to pop up! It's telling me an important thing. I just can't get it to show up in Markers or Problems.

Comment: Do other warnings/errors show up normally?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes.

Comment: Wow. Does the Error Log view show anything interesting? Have you tried to download a fresh eclipse instance, unzip it and make a simple _Hello switch on enum_ project with the right compiler settings turned on?

Comment: How did you configure your Eclipse to show that warning (at least in that place) despite the `default`? Don't get me wrong, I do not doubt you, but AFAIK this is not standard behaviour, and otherwise we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: What are your installed plugins?

Comment: @tobias_k From OP's comment on a deleted answer: _Window-Preferences-Java-Compiler-Erorrs/Warnings - Incomplete switch cases on enum. I have this set to "Warning", and "Signal even if 'default' case exists" is on._

Comment: Slanec: Error Log does not show anything interesting.

Comment: stuXnet: I have the following plugins: AspectJ Compiler, AspectJ Development Tools, Cross References Tools, Eclipse Weaving Service Feature, UCDetector.

Comment: Slanec: I just tried downloading a fresh copy of Eclipse, not the Java EE version I use normally, and it works here - the warning appears both in Problems and Markers. Have to figure out what is different now...

Comment: I'm afraid that nobody will be able to reproduce this. Let's try pinpointing it. You can try one more easy thing - start a new workspace and test in that. If the problem disappears, you might have to switch workspaces / clean the workspace. Try importing the settings from thwe old eclipse to the new eclipse - does it break again?

Comment: When I set that option, it shows the warning in all the places. Have you tried unsetting the option and setting it again?

Comment: Slanec: I guess so, I'll start on it now. 
tobias_k: yep, just did it and it did not help.

Comment: Slanec: yep, old Eclipse + new workspace helps. So the workspace is corrupted somehow - I'd still prefer to keep it. Any idea which config could be broken? I'll dive into it now and try to pinpoint it.

Comment: Unfortunately not. You can the various workspace cleaning possibilities available to eclipse (there are some command line arguments to do that) and/or when creating a new workspace, you can copy some of the the current one's settings. This is all black magic to me, though, so ... good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing an error or warning in the source editor, but it does not show up in problems view, you have likely disabled automatic build. The markers in the problem view will only show up once the build runs. The markers in the source editor will be available shortly after you are done typing, regardless of the build.

So..

1. Refresh the project
2. Trigger clean build from the project menu
3. The marker should show up at this point in the problems view
4. Either turn automatic build on or remember to trigger the build manually when you want to look at the problems view

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case. I have been seeing this error for several months now, and in the meantime I've rebuilt this application like a million times. I have the Auto-build on for 99.9% of time.